# MySQL Get the integer value between two strings

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to get the integer value between two specific strings but I am stacked a little bit.

Example full string:

> "The real ABC4_ string is probably company secret."

I need to get the "4" between "**ABC**" and "**_**". First I've came up with following script:

```
select substring_index(substring_index('The real ABC4_ string is probably company secret.', 'ABC', -1),'_', 1);
```

It gives me 4, perfect! But the problem is if ABC occurs more than one time in the string it fails. I can't simply increase the counter also since I don't know how many times it will be in the future. I have to get first occurrence of that regex: ABC[DIGIT]_

I've seen REGEXP_SUBSTR function but since we use older version of MySQL than 8.0 I can't use it also.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you need to do it in app code.

Comment: @RickJames Yes I had to move this to code, it's probably the most efficient (actually the only one I came up with) solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using Regex, here is an approach using `LOCATE()`, and other string functions:

```
SET @input_string = 'The real ABC4_ string is probably company secret.';

SELECT TRIM(LEADING 'ABC' 
              FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                     SUBSTR(@input_string FROM 
                       LOCATE('ABC', @input_string)
                           )
                     ,'_', 1
                     )
           ) AS number_extracted;

| number_extracted |
| ---------------- |
| 4                |
```

### [View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r4qt2HhDrpJuLk2SBHSruP/1)

Comment: For a string like this it fails: SET @input_string = 'The real ABC_ string is probably company secretABC4_.';

Comment: Except duplicate cases like mine (in the previous comment) it works perfectly, I am approving the answer but please keep in mind this scenario dear future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of (ab)using the `LOCATE()` function:

```
select    substr('The real ABC4_ string is probably company secret.',
   locate('ABC', 'The real ABC4_ string is probably company secret.') + 3,
      locate('_','The real ABC4_ string is probably company secret.') - 
   locate('ABC', 'The real ABC4_ string is probably company secret.') - 3) AS num;
```

Comment: For a string like this it fails: SET @input_string = 'The real ABC_ string is probably company secretABC4_.'; As I understand from the query, you are looking for the first ABC string than the first _ string and get between those two. I need to look for all the scenarios like 1- ABC exists, 2- _ exists, 3- integer between these two exists 4- If there is more than one satisfying below rules, take the first one.